# Select from 4th line onwards Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, outlook

I am using the following code to copy text and images from Microsoft Word and paste to the body of an Outlook e-mail. I am trying to exclude the first 4 lines from being copied (this code is copying everything in the document). How can I go about doing this?

```
Sub CopycontentintoOutlook()

Dim oMailItem As Object
Dim oWordApp As Object
Dim oWordDoc As Object
Dim oMailWordDoc As Object

Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oWordDoc = ActiveDocument

oWordDoc.Content.Copy

Set oMailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMailItem = oMailApp.CreateItem(0)

With oMailItem
.To = "email"
.Subject = "This email contains Word-formatted text"
.Display
End With

Set oMailWordDoc = oMailApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

oMailWordDoc.Application.Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

I am also wondering if it is possible to use the text in the first line and set this as the email subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GoTo()` function with the `wdGoToLine` value to set the insertion point to a specific line. From there, the `MoveEnd()` function can set the end of your selection to the end of your document.

```
' Set start to line 4...   
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=4

' Select up to end of document...
Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdStory
```